# What T-SQL query would retrieve all values of the Email column where values of First_Name and Last_ Name columns are in the Email column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, where-clause

There's a table with 3 columns, 'First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email'. Some values in Email column contain First_Name and Last_Name column values concatenated together. I.e, Email = 'JohnSmith22@example.com' where First_Name = 'John', Last_Name = 'Smith'.

Other Email values for some rows are unrelated. I.e First_Name = 'Steven', Last_Name = 'Paul', Email = 'random12345@example2.com'. What query would retrieve only values of Email column, where First_Name and Last_Name are in the column?

Comment: Is "Han" "Solo" in "SolomonChantelle@Queasy.tv"? Does the order matter? What if the names overlap in the email address, e.g. "Sonny" "Johnson" in "JohnsonNyquist@Math.edu"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What query would retrieve only values of Email column, where First_Name and Last_Name are in the column?

If you want first and last name in the column -- but other characters as well -- I would suggest:

```
where email like '%' + first_name + '%@%' and
      email like '%' + last_name + '%@%'
```

This checks that the first and last names are before the `@`, in any order -- and with any other characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `email` starts with the concatenation of the first and last names, using `like`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where email like first_name + last_name + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of the name field have a heterogeneous **character case**, you need to convert it to lower and check. The other thing is sometimes **the order of First and Last name in the email might be different** so you need to consider this case as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM theTable
WHERE lower(email) LIKE '%' + lower(name) + '%' + LOWER(lastname) + '%'
    OR lower(email) LIKE '%' + lower(lastname) + '%' + LOWER(name) + '%'
```

Comment: I do like the consistent use of lowercasing ;) I would hate database design/setting/collation, where lower and upper case characters are different :(